# Phenolphthalein + sodium carbonate and phenolphthalein + sodium bicarbonate

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, aqueous-solution

What would the word equations be for the following two situations?

Initially $\ce{Na2CO3}$ and $\ce{NaHCO3}$ were present as 2 unknown powders, dissolved in water, and phenolphthalein was added to identify them.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry SE. We have the policy which states that ‎you should explicitly show your thoughts, effort and attempts to understand underlying principles and solve the question.  It'll make us certain that ‎we aren't doing your homework for you. ( As homework is considered literal homework, exams, self-study questions, puzzles, worked examples etc.)  Please provide your full reasoning or thoughts on this, otherwise, the  question may get closed.‎ See [Homework](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange)

Answer (score 1):

Phenolphthalein is colorless for acidic solution, viz. upto $\mathrm{p}H=8$, and for $\mathrm{p}H>8$, it shows pink color. $\ce{NaHCO3}$ is an amphoteric salt with $\mathrm{p}H$ value close to 8, so phenolphthalein will be colorless. But $\ce{Na2CO3}$ being a basic salt, solution will show pink color.